# Multiple or 1 JSON File

Tags: json, qt

I'm creating a questionnaire application in Qt, where surveys are created, and users log on and complete these surveys. I am saving these as JSON.
Each survey could have 60+ questions, and are completed multiple teams by different people. 
Is it more appropriate to save as 1 JSON file,  or a file for each Survey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Database rather than a JSON file. You can use JSON to serialize data and transfer it through processes and computers or servers, but you don't want to save big data to a JSON file.

Anyway if that's what you want to do I would save each survey in a different JSON file. Maybe keep them in order by assigning a unique identifier to each file (name of the file) so that you can find and search for them easily.

One single file would be a single point of failure, and when reading and writing it there would be concurrency problems. One file for each survey should soothe the problem.

Comment: What sort of database would you suggest?

Comment: If you are only working locally I would suggest SQLite. Otherwise any SQL DBMS: PostgreSQL, MySQL ecc...